# Use XQuery to get at this data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xquery, xquery-sql

I am new to XQuery and am having some problems with it.  Here is my example.

I have this variable:

```
declare @xmlDoc XML
```

it has the following xml stored in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Table1">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Sharedparam" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Antoher" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="RandomParam2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="MoreParam" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ResultsParam" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <Table1>
    <Sharedparam>shared</Sharedparam>
    <Antoher>sahre</Antoher>
    <RandomParam2>Good stuff</RandomParam2>
    <MoreParam>and more</MoreParam>
    <ResultsParam>2</ResultsParam>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Sharedparam>Hey</Sharedparam>
    <Antoher>what </Antoher>
    <RandomParam2>do you</RandomParam2>
    <MoreParam>think</MoreParam>
    <ResultsParam>2</ResultsParam>
  </Table1>
  <Table1 />
</NewDataSet>
```

How can I select all the values of Sharedparam?  (Or really any decent query that returns values (not xml) would be great.)

What I am really looking to do is get a result set like this:

```
Name             Value1          Value2          Value3        Value4
Sharedparam      shared          Hey             Null          Null
Another          share           what            Null          Null
....
```

This would have me ignoring any data beyond "Value4" (and that is acceptable for my use of this data).

Comment: That's an odd layout. You expect columns Sharedparam,Antoher etc: not rows. And if i read that right, Table1 `maxOccurs="unbounded"` which means an variable number of columns = not SQL

Comment: I would be ignoring anything beyond Value4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    TBL.SParam.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @xmldoc.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table1/Sharedparam') AS TBL(SParam)
```

Gives me an output of:

```
(No column name)
shared
Hey
```

**Update:** if you want to get at all the XML elements and their values inside the `<Table1>` elements, you can use this XQuery:

```
SELECT
    TBL.SParam.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 'Attribute',
    TBL.SParam.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 'Value'
FROM
    @xmldoc.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table1/*') AS TBL(SParam)
```

which outputs:

```
Attribute            Value
Sharedparam          shared
Antoher              sahre
RandomParam2         Good stuff
MoreParam            and more
ResultsParam         2
Sharedparam          Hey
Antoher              what 
RandomParam2         do you
MoreParam            think
ResultsParam         2
```

**Update #2:** to get the values of the first `<Table1>` and the second `<Table1>` XML node next to one another, you need to do two calls to `.nodes()` - once retrieving the first node, the other time the second one. It gets a bit hairy, especially if you want to extend that even further - and performance is going to be abysmal - but it works :-)

```
SELECT
    TBL.SParam.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 'Attribute',
    TBL.SParam.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 'Value 1',
    TBL2.SParam2.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 'Value 2'
FROM
    @xmldoc.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table1[1]/*') AS TBL(SParam)
INNER JOIN
    @xmldoc.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table1[2]/*') AS TBL2(SParam2) ON TBL.SParam.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') = TBL2.SParam2.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
```

Gives an output of:

```
Attribute      Value 1     Value 2
Sharedparam    shared       Hey
ResultsParam      2          2
RandomParam2   Good stuff   do you
Antoher        sahre        what 
MoreParam      and more     think
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help!  I thought I could take it the rest of the way by my self, but I am stuck...   Is there a way to get the values for both Table[1] and Table[2]  on the same row next to the name?  (like the example output in my question)  I can do it for a single "attribute".  But I can't seem to get it to repeat for the rest of the attributes.

Answer (score 2):

That's an odd layout. You expect columns Sharedparam,Antoher etc: not rows.

And if I read that right, Table1 `maxOccurs="unbounded"` which means an variable number of columns = not SQL which is fixed column type and number

To read each tag as a column (which are fixed and finite) you'd do this:

```
SELECT
   x.item.value('(Sharedparam)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS Sharedparam,
   x.item.value('(Antoher)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS Antoher,
   x.item.value('(SharedRandomParam2param)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS RandomParam2,
   ...
FROM
   @xmlDoc.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table1') x(item)
```